# Passing a method value to member of a class in java

Tags: java

I have a class dedicated to encode and decode files. The encode method receives in its signature a string corresponding to the file path to encode. The `encodeFileToBase64Binary` is returning a simple String that I use to build a JSON object.

My objective would be to get the file name to the decode folder in order to create a new file. Those two methods are called at distinct moments.

```
public class FileConverterBase64 {

    private ApplicationProperties properties = new ApplicationProperties();
    private String toSignFilePath;

    public String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String filePath) throws IOException {
        this.toSignFilePath = filePath;
        byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePath));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
    }

    public void stringDecodeFileToPdf(String encodedFile) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("toSignFilePath : "  + toSignFilePath);

        // deposit repository 
        String folder = properties.getProperty("document.signed");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

        String outputFileName = folder + "\\" +  now + "" + toSignFilePath + "-signed";
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedFile);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(outputFileName), decodedBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You told us "what I want", and "here is some code". But what is your problem/question?!

Comment: I have no doubt that the file you are trying to decode is actually a PDF file, but if you're designing your `FileConverterBase64` class to have a `stringDecodeFileToPdf` method then you're doing something wrong; there is no PDF functionality in the class. Neither is every string a base 64 string and no base 64 string is a "file", so the method identifier has been named incorrectly as well.

Comment: the method do convert a encoded file in pdf. the only issue is that i try to pass the file name value from the first method to the second.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but aren't you asking what `toSignFilePath` is already there to do? Or where does the "decode folder" come into play? Are you asking how to save/restore the variable called `folder`?

Comment: I want to pass the filePath value from encodeFileToBase64Binary to toSignFilePath and then use the value i set into stringDecodeFileToPdf

Comment: I finally solved my issue. I have the path in the first method when I call it and I passed the value to all the methods I used before reaching the stringDecodeFileToPdf